# Float pointer malloc array receiving into array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am writing a code which requires me to use the malloc function, feed input into an array, determine and print the average as well as how each array value relates to the average. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
  int i, n;
  float* numbers;
  float sum, average;
  sum = 0;
  printf("How many numbers? ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  numbers = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
  printf("Enter %d decimal numbers\n", n);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    scanf("%f", &numbers[i]);
    printf("%f\n", &numbers[i]);
    sum = sum + numbers[i];
}

printf("%f\n", &sum);
 average = sum / n;
 printf("The average was %f\n", &average);
 for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    if (numbers[i] < average)
        printf("%f is less than the average\n" , &average);
    else if (numbers[i] > average)
        printf("%f is less than the average\n" , &average);
    else
        printf("%f is average\n" , &average);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The print statement in the very first for loop I was using to check whether or not my array is receiving the input properly, it is not, as shown by my output, which is below, my question is why is my array not receiving the values?

```
How many numbers? 4
Enter 4 decimal numbers
4
0.000000
4
0.000000
4
0.000000
4
0.000000
0.000000
The average was 0.000000
0.000000 is average
0.000000 is average
0.000000 is average
0.000000 is average
```

Comment: Why are you allocating an array of integers and assigning it to a `float` pointer?

Comment: You're probably lucky that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`, but it is bad style to rely on that!  Given `float *numbers;`, the line `numbers = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));` should be making your compiler give groans and witters about type mismatches, etc.  If it isn't, you need to turn on more warnings or get a better compiler.  And you need to think carefully about the code you're writing.  You should also be checking the return value from `scanf()`; it may be telling you it couldn't interpret the input at all.  Also, `printf("%f\n", &numbers[i]);` is wrong; you're passing a pointer!  Don't!

Comment: You keep giving the wrong argument to `printf`. You want to print `sum`, not `&sum`

Answer (score 5):

A few corrected issues:

1)

```
numbers = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Allocation of memory for int was replaced with the allocation for `float.` 
Cast is not required.

```
numbers = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
```

2)

```
 printf("%f\n", &numbers[i]);
```

The intention is not to print a pointer to `number[i]` but the `number[i]` itself.

```
printf("%f\n", numbers[i]);
```

This type of issue was corrected for a few other printing places.

3) Final prints was corrected, logically program required printing the `numbers[i]` not the `average`

```
if (numbers[i] < average)
        printf("%f is less than the average\n" , numbers[i] );
    else if (numbers[i] > average)
        printf("%f is more than the average\n" , numbers[i] );
```

Corrected program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
  int i,n;

  float* numbers;
  float sum, average;
  sum = 0;

  printf("How many numbers? ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  numbers = malloc(n * sizeof(float));

  printf("Enter %d decimal numbers:\n", n);

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    scanf("%f", &numbers[i]);

    printf("%f\n", numbers[i]);

    sum = sum + numbers[i];
  }

  printf("%f\n", sum);

  average = sum / n;
  printf("The average was %f\n", average);

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (numbers[i] < average)
        printf("%f is less than the average\n" , numbers[i] );
    else if (numbers[i] > average)
        printf("%f is more than the average\n" , numbers[i] );
    else
        printf("%f is average\n" , average);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
How many numbers? Enter 4 decimal numbers:
2
10
5
8
2.000000
10.000000
5.000000
8.000000
25.000000
The average was 6.250000
2.000000 is less than the average
10.000000 is more than the average
5.000000 is less than the average
8.000000 is more than the average
```

Comment: I have corrected my finals prints, I realized I needed to replace the average variable with numbers[i]

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why, instead of posting a code-only answer

Comment: @M.M The reason for code changes was posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
printf("%f\n", &numbers[i]);
```

You're printing a reference to `numbers[i]` instead of the value itself. Try:

```
printf("%f\n", numbers[i]);
```

Same thing for all the other places you print values (i.e. `sum`, `average`). You're getting 0's when you print it because when you take a pointer to one of those values and cast it to a float it is interpreting that as zero.

Perhaps someone else will be able to enlighten us an exactly why that is (i.e. I'm not sure if that is undefined behavior).

In case you're still confused: the reason you have to pass a reference (`&`) to the value to `scanf`, yet the value itself to `printf`, here's the reason: for `scanf` you're telling it "please get a float from the console and put it at this location I am specifying (i.e `&numbers[i]`)". When you call `printf`, you are telling it "please print this value I am giving you (i.e. `numbers[i]`)".

Comment: It's undefined what happens when you pass a pointer to `printf()` and tell it to print a `double` value based on that.  It's simply not worth speculating why it goes wrong — you're doing it wrong (the OP is doing it wrong).  Good compilers help by warning if given the chance.

Comment: the printf("%f\n", &numbers[i]); is used only as a test to check if the array is getting the input I give it, i used the code you suggested and my output was the same, however as a final program this line won't even be in the code, I feel it it something with the scanf statement or my pointer/array, I just cannot find it.

Comment: @Swishy you need to fix it everywhere else you call `printf` as well.

Comment: @Swishy: When I fixed the code, I got the output: `How many numbers? 4
Enter 4 decimal numbers
4 4 3 5` (yes, I entered them all on one line) and then I got the output: `4.000000 4.000000 3.000000 5.000000 16.000000 The average was 4.000000 4.000000 is average 4.000000 is average 4.000000 is less than the average 4.000000 is less than the average` suitably spread over lines. I had to fix the memory allocation line too — my compiler complained (but I insist it complains about dubious practices). It complained when I missed one of the `printf` lines. Print `numbers[i]`, not `average`.

Comment: @Jonathon Leffler I understand, I will practice more to fully understand this

Answer (score 1):

sum=0f;
Writing f so that it is interpreted as float constant instead of double.This doesn't matter much but is good practice and can help striking out a lot of problems.

numbers = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
Since you want a float array and not an integer array.

printf("%f\n",numbers[i]);
Use '&' only when you want to access the address of variable . To access the value stored in the variable simply use the variable name.

printf("Sum is : %f\n", sum);
Writing proper message in output is important.

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { if (numbers[i] < average) printf("%f is less than the average\n" , numbers[i]); else if (numbers[i] > average) printf("%f is less than the average\n" , numbers[i]); else printf("%f is average\n" , numbers[i]); }

You need to print the value of number[i] instead of average.

And remember not to use & in printf unless you want to print a address

Answer (score 0):

First fix the malloc

```
numbers = malloc(n * sizeof(float)); // Not 'int'
```

then fix the *for* and next `printf`

```
printf("%f\n", numbers[i]); // printf wants a value not an address

printf("%f\n", sum);        // same
```

then

```
printf("The average was %f\n", average); // same
```

and the 3 next similar printf.